# Properties of Diagonal Equivalence with Orthogonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has the form:

$$A = D_1 Q D_2$$

where $D_1, D_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are invertible diagonal matrices and $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is an orthogonal matrix.

**Are there any known properties that $A$ has?**